# Insertando registros seleccionados con error "SUBCONSULTA MAS DE UNA LINEA!" en Mariadb

Tags: sql, mariadb

tengo un problema con un Insert, que me da el error de "subconsulta retorna mas de 1 linea", pero he realizado todas las pruebas y no encuentro el problema.
Utilizo Mariadb 10.5.8
Tengo dadas las siguientes tablas

**Tabla privilagios**

```
CREATE TABLE `privilegios` (
    `binario` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `cantidad` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `privilegio` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `texto` VARCHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `usuario` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `FK_privilegios_privilegiosdescripcion` (`privilegio`) USING BTREE,       
    CONSTRAINT `FK_privilegios_privilegiosdescripcion` FOREIGN KEY (`privilegio`) REFERENCES `nueva`.`privilegiosdescripcion` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=143
;
```

**Tabla Privilegios descripción**

```
CREATE TABLE `privilegiosdescripcion` (
    `binario` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `cantidad` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `descripcion` VARCHAR(300) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `habilitado` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `nombre` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `texto` VARCHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `tipodeprivilegio` INT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
    UNIQUE INDEX `nombre` (`nombre`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `id` (`id`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=7261
;
```

Cada privilegio esta asignado a un usuario, por eso esta el campo "usuario" en la tabla privilegios. Privilegiosdescripciòn tiene el detalle de todos los privilegios que se pueden asignar a un usuario, y en esta esta la descripcion y si la asignacion por defecto de la misma.
Cada privilegio se divide en 3 tipos, Privilegio de texto, Privilegio de numero (decimal) y privilegio binario, Realmente no es necesario tratar ahora sus funcionalidades pero explico esto para entender la siguiente consulta:
**Consulta con el problema**

```
INSERT INTO privilegios (usuario, privilegio, binario, texto, cantidad) SELECT -1, d.id, 1, d.texto, d.cantidad FROM privilegiosdescripcion d WHERE d.id NOT IN (SELECT privilegio FROM privilegios WHERE usuario = -1);
```

LA anterior consulta lo que realiza es al usuario "-1"  la insersion de todos los privilegios con el dato binario 1 para darle permiso por defecto porque es el "SUPER USUARIO", estoy utilizando INSERT INTO Con un SELECT donde busco las secuencias no introducidas con un "NOT IN"

La consulta sola, de select funciona correctamente, pero cuando la uno a insert, da el error. Y no deberia presentarlo sino insertar los valores a la tabla privilegios

He realizado la siguiente procedimiento para realizar estas inserciones, mi idea es optimizar este lo mas posible:

**Procedimiento "Verificarpermisos"**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `verificarpermisos`()
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN
DECLARE _usuario INT(11);
DECLARE fin INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE buscarpermisos CURSOR FOR
SELECT id FROM empleados where eliminado = 0;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET fin=1;
OPEN buscarpermisos;
iniciodecomparacion: LOOP
FETCH buscarpermisos INTO _usuario;
IF fin = 1 THEN
LEAVE iniciodecomparacion;
END IF;
IF (_usuario = -1) then
INSERT INTO privilegios (usuario, privilegio, binario, texto, cantidad) SELECT -1, d.id, 1, d.texto, d.cantidad FROM privilegiosdescripcion d WHERE d.id NOT IN (SELECT privilegio FROM privilegios WHERE usuario = -1);
else
INSERT INTO privilegios (usuario, privilegio, binario, texto, cantidad) SELECT _usuario, d.id, d.binario, d.texto, d.cantidad FROM privilegiosdescripcion d WHERE d.id NOT IN (SELECT privilegio FROM privilegios WHERE usuario = _usuario);
end if;

/*INSERT INTO privilegios (usuario, privilegio, binario, texto, cantidad) SELECT _usuario, d.id, 1, d.texto, d.cantidad FROM privilegiosdescripcion d LEFT JOIN privilegios p on d.id = p.privilegio where p.usuario= _usuario AND p.privilegio is null;*/

/*INSERT INTO privilegios (usuario, privilegio, binario, texto, cantidad) SELECT _usuario, d.id, d.binario, d.texto, d.cantidad FROM privilegiosdescripcion d LEFT JOIN privilegios p on d.id = p.privilegio where p.usuario= _usuario AND p.privilegio is null;*/

END LOOP iniciodecomparacion;
CLOSE buscarpermisos;
DELETE FROM privilegios WHERE privilegio NOT IN (SELECT privilegiosdescripcion.id FROM privilegiosdescripcion);
END
```

En este procedimiento utilize un loop para verificar usuario por usuario los privilegios y agregarlos si no estan agregados. He intentado realizar este procedimiento con una sola consulta pero no he podido, podrian decirme si se puede simplificar y donde esta el problema de con la consulta en cuestion que muestro anteriormente? espero que alguien que sepa me pueda guiar

Comment: si esto: SELECT id FROM empleados where eliminado = 0;
 devuelve mas de una fila, cuando haga FETCH buscarpermisos INTO _usuario;
no va a traer justamente el error que marcas?

Comment: Elimine ese paso y sigue tirando el mismo error, INSERT INTO privilegios (usuario, privilegio, binario, texto, cantidad) SELECT -1, d.id, 1, d.texto, d.cantidad FROM privilegiosdescripcion d WHERE d.id NOT IN (SELECT privilegio FROM privilegios );